# How to add html into Angular in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that add lots of html when user clicks a button.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('testProduct', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                var html;
                html = '<div>… a lot of html tags and contents………….'; 
                // a lot of html tags
                //I want to link to a html file like product.html 
                //instead of defining here.
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    $('.product').remove();
                    elem.closest('div').append(html);
                })
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Is there anyway I can link the html to another file? like `templateUrl:product.html`? I can't use it here because I only want to add those html when user clicks a button.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click event create an element like `<div ng-include="foo.html"></div>` and pass it to angular.element. Then append it to the DOM. Once appended use the injected $compile service. `$compile(dynamicIncludeElement)(scope)`.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('testProduct', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                var html = angular.element('<div ng-include="'product.html'"></div>');

                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    var compiledHtml = $compile(html)(scope);
                    elem.append(compiledHtml);
                })
            }
        };
    }
);
```

The other alternative would be to acquire the HTML yourself and compile it.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('testProduct', function($http, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {

                elem.bind('click', function() {

                    $http.get('product.html')
                        .success(function(data) {
                            var compiledHtml = $compile(data)(scope);
                            elem.append(compiledHtml);
                        }
                    );

                })
            }
        };
    }
);
```